# Would a question on how to clean/maintain scuba goggles be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

My question is along the lines of how to properly clean and maintain scuba goggles so as to avoid them fogging during use.

I considered asking here on Travel, [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), and over on [sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/).

I'm not too sure it really fits into any of the above.

Curious to know if anyone can recommend a site?

Comment: "Mask," not goggles, if you want to avoid sniggering. :-)

Comment: Sports is unlikely to be receptive, unless the question concerns competitive scuba diving or is close enough that it will pass the bar. The Great Outdoors is where this would get migrated otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will not be on topic on Travel, neither on Home Improvement. I am not sure about Sport, as I never go there.

There are several scuba questions on [The Great Outdoors,](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) again it might be not really on topic but it will not be as far off as it will be on Travel.
If you are looking for untraditional methods, [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) might be the right place.

I guess a good search on 'stack exchange' might help you, as even the regulars on some of the stacks will not know all the options.